# WS2DAS- RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I am trying to connect to HBase using wso2-das server.

I need to connect to Hbase from wso2DAS, I followed all steps to do setup from below link. WSO2DAS not connecting to Hbase.Master and region servers, all are running fine. but keep on getting  "Can't get the locations error"

https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=45952699

Master and region servers all are running fine. still getting

[2016-10-23 16:15:11,477] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer} -  Error while creating the table Or setting the schema for table: test_2
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.commons.exception.AnalyticsException: Error checking existence of table TEST_2 for tenant -1234 : Can't get the locations
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.hbase.HBaseAnalyticsRecordStore.tableExists(HBaseAnalyticsRecordStore.java:140)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.hbase.HBaseAnalyticsRecordStore.createTable(HBaseAnalyticsRecordStore.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.createTableFinal(AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.createTable(AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.java:378)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.api.CarbonAnalyticsAPI.createTable(CarbonAnalyticsAPI.java:134)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.addEventStore(AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.java:108)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.deploy(AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.(ClientScanner.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:794)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:403)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.hbase.HBaseAnalyticsRecordStore.tableExists(HBaseAnalyticsRecordStore.java:137)
    ... 23 more
[2016-10-23 16:15:11,481] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer} -  Error while deploying file: test_2.xml for tenant id: -1234
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.exception.AnalyticsEventStoreException: Error while creating the table Or setting the schema for table: test_2
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.addEventStore(AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.java:125)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.deploy(AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at 
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.co